# Catching ValueError: unknown url type: urllib2 Python

Tags: python

I'm getting the following exception when I enter an invalid URL: `ValueError: unknown url type: blob`

I'm trying to catch this error with the following code but it's not working:

```
try:
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    conn =  urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = conn.read()
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print 'Error: Invalid URL'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you notice, the base error is a `ValueError`, so

```
import urllib2
url = 'blob'
try:
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    conn =  urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = conn.read()
except ValueError, e:
    print 'Error: Invalid URL'
```